# How can I change Index of an object in a list without deleting and re-adding the item in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of class objects in a list . I want to change index of -1 element to 0 . I want rest of the objects to shift their index automatically . I cannot delete the item and re-add it into list using Insert() . What can I do ? I want to keep the list intact as it is but just need to change index of some elements within list

here is an example

list -----> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

what I want to do is change 0 to 0th index from -1 index value

result required ----> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Please note that I have a list of class objects in a kivy(module) class . I cannot delete and re - add the same widget . I want to change the Index

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0]
print(f'original : {l}')

## dynamically generate "order"
order = [n for n in range(len(l))]
order.insert(0, order[-1])
del order[-1]
print(f'order    : {order}')

## rearrange the list with generated "order"
l = [l[i] for i in order]
print(f'final    : {l}')
```

Output:

```
original : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0]
order    : [7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
final    : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```